# Effects not triggering any actions?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am quite new to NGRx, I am trying to use Effects on my little project as date uses external data I decided to put it in the effects, so console not showing any errors, program sees all actions except action that is used in effects (CountUpdatedAtAction ), I am using redux devtools there is not updatedAt action triggering when I am updating count, all other actions works as expected

### count.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {
  countActionsType,
  CountUpdatedAtAction,
} from './reducers/count/count.actions';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect()
  updatedAt$() {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        countActionsType.increase,
        countActionsType.decrease,
        countActionsType.clear,
        countActionsType.updatedAt
      ),
      map(() => {
        return new CountUpdatedAtAction({
          updatedAt: Date.now(),
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

### count.reducer.ts

```
import { CountActions, countActionsType } from './count.actions';

export const COUNT_NODE = 'count';

export interface ICountState {
  count: number;
  updatedAt: number;
}

const initialState: ICountState = {
  count: 0,
  updatedAt: Date.now(),
};

export const countReducer = (state = initialState, actions: CountActions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case countActionsType.increase:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1,
      };
    case countActionsType.decrease:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1,
      };
    case countActionsType.clear:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: 0,
      };
    case countActionsType.updatedAt:
      return {
        ...state,
        updatedAt: actions.payload.updatedAt,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### count.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export enum countActionsType {
  increase = '[COUNT] increase',
  decrease = '[COUNT] decrease',
  clear = '[COUNT] clear',
  updatedAt = '[COUNT] updated at',
}

export class CountIncreaseAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.increase;
}

export class CountDecreaseAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.decrease;
}

export class CountClearAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.clear;
}

export class CountUpdatedAtAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.updatedAt;

  constructor(
    public payload: {
      updatedAt: number;
    }
  ) {}
}

export type CountActions =
  | CountIncreaseAction
  | CountDecreaseAction
  | CountClearAction
  | CountUpdatedAtAction;
```

### count.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ICountState } from './reducers/count/count.reducer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { selectCount, selectUpdatedAt } from './reducers/count/count.selectors';
import {
  CountIncreaseAction,
  CountDecreaseAction,
  CountClearAction,
} from './reducers/count/count.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public count$: Observable<number> = this.store$.pipe(select(selectCount));
  public isButtonDisabled$: Observable<boolean> = this.count$.pipe(
    map((count) => count <= 0)
  );
  public updatedAt$: Observable<number> = this.store$.pipe(
    select(selectUpdatedAt)
  );

  constructor(private store$: Store<ICountState>) {}

  increase() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountIncreaseAction());
  }

  decrease() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountDecreaseAction());
  }

  clear() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountClearAction());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your effects, see the docs https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects.

If that doesn't solve it, provide a reproduction please.

EDIT:

You have to add the effect to the effects module:

```
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
```

Comment: EffectsModule.forRoot([]) it was in app.module.ts, i modified to EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]), now app is crashed and nothing is working! Should do it like this or?

Comment: [link to GitHub Repo](https://github.com/nurdared/https-github.com-nurdared-ngrx-tutorial-gromax) please help me!

Comment: i have added now app is crashed and cant do anything

Comment: it is infinite loop now